# Как интегрировать шаблон с WordPress на Bitrix?

Tags: wordpress, битрикс

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вставить скачанный шаблон WordPress на Bitrix, может быть, есть ссылки с примером? В интернете есть множество статей про то, как перенести простенькие html-шаблоны, а как перенести php-шаблоны - нет.

Comment: Забудьте. Нерешаемая задача.

Comment: Почему??  Неужели это так сложно?

Comment: Это называется в WordPress не шаблон, а тема. В ней обычно тысячи строк. Через пятую на 10 строку идут вызовы функций из ядра WordPress

Comment: Вот точная формулировка задания, которое мне нужно сделать: Интеграция верстки в систему битриксовых шаблонов
Нужно взять готовый шаблон под вордпресс и создать на его основе шаблон битрикса. По окончании шага сайт должен выглядеть также, как демка шаблона. На всякий случай уточняю: не надо верстать с нуля, надо использовать верстку из шаблона, удалив из нее специфические для вордпресса вещи.
Ссылка на шаблон: 
http://wp-templates.ru/fashify/

Демо шаблона: 
https://wpstash.com/fashify/
Неужели это невыполнимо?

Comment: Это - другое. Вам надо "вырезать" весь код, относящийся в WP. Фактически, оставив просто генерацию html средствами php. Но и это - очень много работы. Проще сверстать заново. Вам все так легко кажется, потому что вы в код тем никогда не заглядывали.

Comment: А как можно понять, что именно "этот код" нужно вырезать?

Comment: Для этого нужно разбираться в WordPress

Comment: а можете посоветовать хорошие источники для того, чтобы научиться разбираться?

Comment: https://wp-kama.ru/